# Hide billing address from checkout page but keep the information

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, account, user-registration

I want to hide the billing address from the checkout page (not remove it) and make the billing address set for the first time when registered?

To allow display on the bill .pdf

I add this code:

```
<?php

add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_override_checkout_fields' );

function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
    unset($fields['billing']['billing_first_name']);
    unset($fields['billing']['billing_last_name']);
    unset($fields['billing']['billing_company']);
    unset($fields['billing']['billing_address_1']);
    unset($fields['billing']['billing_address_2']);
    unset($fields['billing']['billing_city']);
    unset($fields['billing']['billing_postcode']);
    unset($fields['billing']['billing_country']);
    unset($fields['billing']['billing_state']);
    unset($fields['billing']['billing_phone']);
    unset($fields['order']['order_comments']);
    unset($fields['billing']['billing_address_2']);
    unset($fields['billing']['billing_postcode']);
    unset($fields['billing']['billing_company']);
    unset($fields['billing']['billing_last_name']);
    unset($fields['billing']['billing_email']);
    unset($fields['billing']['billing_city']);
    return $fields;
}
```

And by adding this code, the billing address wasn't added to the pdf bill

So which code shall I add or edit?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First step: Make the billing address set for the first time when registered**

1) You need to change WooCommerce setting for registration. 
WooCommerce **Settings** > **Account *(tab)***:

[image: Registration Options]

2) Adding Billing fields in user registration **My Account** page:

Base: [How to add custom fields in user registration on the "My Account" page](https://support.woothemes.com/hc/en-us/articles/203182373-How-to-add-custom-fields-in-user-registration-on-the-My-Account-page)

The customized code *(copy that code in the function.php file of your active child theme or theme)*:

```php
if( !is_admin() )
{
    // Function to check starting char of a string
    function startsWith($haystack, $needle)
    { 
        return $needle === '' || strpos($haystack, $needle) === 0;
    }

    // Custom function to display the Billing Address form to registration page
    function my_custom_function()
    {
        global $woocommerce;
        $checkout = $woocommerce->checkout();

        ?>
            <h3><?php _e( 'Billing Address', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h3>
        <?php

        foreach ($checkout->checkout_fields['billing'] as $key => $field) :
            woocommerce_form_field( $key, $field, $checkout->get_value( $key ) );
        endforeach;
    }
    add_action('register_form','my_custom_function');


    // Custom function to save Usermeta or Billing Address of registered user
    function save_address($user_id)
    {
        global $woocommerce;
        $address = $_POST;

        foreach ($address as $key => $field) :
            if(startsWith($key,'billing_'))
            {
                // Condition to add firstname and last name to user meta table
                if($key == 'billing_first_name' || $key == 'billing_last_name')
                {
                    $new_key = explode('billing_',$key);
                    update_user_meta( $user_id, $new_key[1], $_POST[$key] );
                }
                update_user_meta( $user_id, $key, $_POST[$key] );
            }
        endforeach;
    }
    add_action('woocommerce_created_customer','save_address');


    // Registration page billing address form Validation
    function custom_validation()
    {
        global $woocommerce;
        $address = $_POST;

        foreach ($address as $key => $field) :

            // Validation: Required fields
            if(startsWith($key,'billing_'))
            {

                if($key == 'billing_country' && $field == '')
                {
                    $woocommerce->add_error( '' . __( 'ERROR', 'woocommerce' ) . ': ' . __( 'Please select a country.', 'woocommerce' ) );
                }

                if($key == 'billing_first_name' && $field == '')
                {
                    $woocommerce->add_error( '' . __( 'ERROR', 'woocommerce' ) . ': ' . __( 'Please enter first name.', 'woocommerce' ) );
                }

                if($key == 'billing_last_name' && $field == '')
                {
                    $woocommerce->add_error( '' . __( 'ERROR', 'woocommerce' ) . ': ' . __( 'Please enter last name.', 'woocommerce' ) );
                }

                if($key == 'billing_address_1' && $field == '')
                {
                    $woocommerce->add_error( '' . __( 'ERROR', 'woocommerce' ) . ': ' . __( 'Please enter address.', 'woocommerce' ) );
                }

                if($key == 'billing_city' && $field == '')
                {
                    $woocommerce->add_error( '' . __( 'ERROR', 'woocommerce' ) . ': ' . __( 'Please enter city.', 'woocommerce' ) );
                }

                if($key == 'billing_state' && $field == '')
                {
                    $woocommerce->add_error( '' . __( 'ERROR', 'woocommerce' ) . ': ' . __( 'Please enter state.', 'woocommerce' ) );
                }

                if($key == 'billing_postcode' && $field == '')
                {
                    $woocommerce->add_error( '' . __( 'ERROR', 'woocommerce' ) . ': ' . __( 'Please enter a postcode.', 'woocommerce' ) );
                }

                if($key == 'billing_email' && $field == '')
                {
                    $woocommerce->add_error( '' . __( 'ERROR', 'woocommerce' ) . ': ' . __( 'Please enter billing email address.', 'woocommerce' ) );
                }

                if($key == 'billing_phone' && $field == '')
                {
                    $woocommerce->add_error( '' . __( 'ERROR', 'woocommerce' ) . ': ' . __( 'Please enter phone number.', 'woocommerce' ) );
                }
            }

        endforeach;
    }
    add_action('register_post','custom_validation');

}
```

**Second step: Hidding the billing address from the checkout whiteout remove it**

You will need to use CSS targeting the billing block fields with `display: none !important;` rule.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this clear answer! but what I want is to not ask for the billing address again in the checkout page I added some codes to remove it at the function.php file but then it doesnt get the address set when registred it was empty!

Comment: @AbdelazizMirad So may be you need to to disable checkbox on woocommerce settings for **Display returning customer login reminder on the "Checkout" page**. Could you provide a link to your website? To hide billing fields on checkout is better to use CSS rule as i said.

Comment: I tryied everything in Checkout and My Account tabs, yeah there is no problem I can hide html/css I need to keep informaton!

Comment: I am using  wordpress theme, and this theme doesn't ask for billing/shipping address when registration! I add some fields for address but it seems it is not considering it as billing address! (Haha nope! I am not french :p)

Comment: @AbdelazizMirad Because you need to use the existing billing fields names and slugs (like in my code example). You can add custom fields, but you need to keep original billing fields terms (slugs). Of course you can change displayed titles. Also you should add custom billing fields in checkout, even if you hide them.