# Add Billing Address to Woocommerce Registration Page

Tags: woocommerce, registration, billing

I found a solution to this problem and added the code found here: [Hide billing address from checkout page but keep the information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37510687/hide-billing-address-from-checkout-page-but-keep-the-information/37511524#37511524)

under "2) Adding Billing fields in user registration My Account page"

This successfully added the billing address to the registration form. The fields from the registration form feed the data into the Woocommerce database perfectly.

That being said the "state" dropdown **doesn't** update when I change the "country" dropdown. The state dropdown **does** update properly depending on the country selected on the checkout page and also under edit address in the "My Account" area but not on the new registration page. So as it currently stands the registration page only works properly for the USA.

Any advice as to how the code needs to be changed to make the "State" dropdown update correctly would be very helpful.

Thanks! 
Mark

Comment: Sorry, it's not clear.  Do you need an answer to this or not?

Comment: Yes, any help would be appreciated. Still trying to solve this problem.

Comment: I am interested in an answer to this question too.

Comment: There's a plugin that'll do it - https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/wc-afour/

Answer (score 4):

You need to use woocommerce_registration_errors for validcation. This code is the same as [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44738509/4912264) but with updated validation method.

```
<?php

// Function to check starting char of a string
function startsWith($haystack, $needle){
    return $needle === '' || strpos($haystack, $needle) === 0;
}


// Custom function to display the Billing Address form to registration page
function zk_add_billing_form_to_registration(){
    global $woocommerce;
    $checkout = $woocommerce->checkout();
    ?>
    <?php foreach ( $checkout->get_checkout_fields( 'billing' ) as $key => $field ) : ?>

        <?php if($key!='billing_email'){ 
            woocommerce_form_field( $key, $field, $checkout->get_value( $key ) );
        } ?>

    <?php endforeach; 
}
add_action('woocommerce_register_form_start','zk_add_billing_form_to_registration');

// Custom function to save Usermeta or Billing Address of registered user
function zk_save_billing_address($user_id){
    global $woocommerce;
    $address = $_POST;
    foreach ($address as $key => $field){
        if(startsWith($key,'billing_')){
            // Condition to add firstname and last name to user meta table
            if($key == 'billing_first_name' || $key == 'billing_last_name'){
                $new_key = explode('billing_',$key);
                update_user_meta( $user_id, $new_key[1], $_POST[$key] );
            }
            update_user_meta( $user_id, $key, $_POST[$key] );
        }
    }

}
add_action('woocommerce_created_customer','zk_save_billing_address');


// Registration page billing address form Validation
function zk_validation_billing_address( $errors ) {
    $address = $_POST;
    foreach ($address as $key => $field) :
        if(startsWith($key,'billing_')){
            if($key == 'billing_country' && $field == ''){
                add_the_error($errors, $key, 'Country');
            }
            if($key == 'billing_first_name' && $field == ''){
                add_the_error($errors, $key, 'First Name');
            }
            if($key == 'billing_last_name' && $field == ''){
                add_the_error($errors, $key, 'Last Name');
            }
            if($key == 'billing_address_1' && $field == ''){
                add_the_error($errors, $key, 'Address');
            }
            if($key == 'billing_city' && $field == ''){
                add_the_error($errors, $key, 'City');
            }
            if($key == 'billing_state' && $field == ''){
                add_the_error($errors, $key, 'State');
            }
            if($key == 'billing_postcode' && $field == ''){
                add_the_error($errors, $key, 'Post Code');
            }
            if($key == 'billing_phone' && $field == ''){
                add_the_error($errors, $key, 'Phone Number');
            }

        }
    endforeach;

    return $errors;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_registration_errors', 'zk_validation_billing_address', 10 );

function add_the_error( $errors, $key, $field_name ) {
    $message = sprintf( __( '%s is a required field.', 'iconic' ), '<strong>' . $field_name . '</strong>' );
    $errors->add( $key, $message );
}
```

Comment: This function does not take into consideration that the "billing_state" field visibility depends on the "billing_country" value. For example if I select "Germany" as the Country, the State field would be hidden, but the required validation for the State would stay there. This will cause the impossibility to save the record.

Answer (score 1):

To add Billing fields on registration page you can use this snippet:

```
<?php

// Function to check starting char of a string
function startsWith($haystack, $needle){
    return $needle === '' || strpos($haystack, $needle) === 0;
}


// Custom function to display the Billing Address form to registration page
function zk_add_billing_form_to_registration(){
    global $woocommerce;
    $checkout = $woocommerce->checkout();
    ?>
    <?php foreach ( $checkout->get_checkout_fields( 'billing' ) as $key => $field ) : ?>

        <?php if($key!='billing_email'){ 
            woocommerce_form_field( $key, $field, $checkout->get_value( $key ) );
        } ?>

    <?php endforeach; 
}
add_action('woocommerce_register_form_start','zk_add_billing_form_to_registration');

// Custom function to save Usermeta or Billing Address of registered user
function zk_save_billing_address($user_id){
    global $woocommerce;
    $address = $_POST;
    foreach ($address as $key => $field){
        if(startsWith($key,'billing_')){
            // Condition to add firstname and last name to user meta table
            if($key == 'billing_first_name' || $key == 'billing_last_name'){
                $new_key = explode('billing_',$key);
                update_user_meta( $user_id, $new_key[1], $_POST[$key] );
            }
            update_user_meta( $user_id, $key, $_POST[$key] );
        }
    }

}
add_action('woocommerce_created_customer','zk_save_billing_address');


// Registration page billing address form Validation
function zk_validation_billing_address(){
    global $woocommerce;
    $address = $_POST;
    foreach ($address as $key => $field) :
        // Validation: Required fields
        if(startsWith($key,'billing_')){
            if($key == 'billing_country' && $field == ''){
                $woocommerce->add_error( '<strong>' . __( 'ERROR', 'woocommerce' ) . '</strong>: ' . __( 'Please select a country.', 'woocommerce' ) );
            }
            if($key == 'billing_first_name' && $field == ''){
                $woocommerce->add_error( '<strong>' . __( 'ERROR', 'woocommerce' ) . '</strong>: ' . __( 'Please enter first name.', 'woocommerce' ) );
            }
            if($key == 'billing_last_name' && $field == ''){
                $woocommerce->add_error( '<strong>' . __( 'ERROR', 'woocommerce' ) . '</strong>: ' . __( 'Please enter last name.', 'woocommerce' ) );
            }
            if($key == 'billing_address_1' && $field == ''){
                $woocommerce->add_error( '<strong>' . __( 'ERROR', 'woocommerce' ) . '</strong>: ' . __( 'Please enter address.', 'woocommerce' ) );
            }
            if($key == 'billing_city' && $field == ''){
                $woocommerce->add_error( '<strong>' . __( 'ERROR', 'woocommerce' ) . '</strong>: ' . __( 'Please enter city.', 'woocommerce' ) );
            }
            if($key == 'billing_state' && $field == ''){
                $woocommerce->add_error( '<strong>' . __( 'ERROR', 'woocommerce' ) . '</strong>: ' . __( 'Please enter state.', 'woocommerce' ) );
            }
            if($key == 'billing_postcode' && $field == ''){
                $woocommerce->add_error( '<strong>' . __( 'ERROR', 'woocommerce' ) . '</strong>: ' . __( 'Please enter a postcode.', 'woocommerce' ) );
            }
            /*
            if($key == 'billing_email' && $field == ''){
                $woocommerce->add_error( '<strong>' . __( 'ERROR', 'woocommerce' ) . '</strong>: ' . __( 'Please enter billing email address.', 'woocommerce' ) );
            }
            */
            if($key == 'billing_phone' && $field == ''){
                $woocommerce->add_error( '<strong>' . __( 'ERROR', 'woocommerce' ) . '</strong>: ' . __( 'Please enter phone number.', 'woocommerce' ) );
            }

        }
    endforeach;
}
add_action('register_post','zk_validation_billing_address');
```

Comment: Great plugin but the validation doesn't seem to work, any ideas?

Comment: I thought I'd worked this out but turns out I haven't. Disabling the save function seems to make the validation work, but I can't find a way to make them both work together :(